# Jquery appendTo not working as I thought it would

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="likelyToBeCalled">
    <div class="likelyOddHeader" id="Test1">
        <div class="likelyOddA">Test1</div>
        <div class="likelyOddB"><img src="image002.png"/></div>
        <div class="timeZone">West</div>

//closing tags here

<div id="unlikelyToBeCalled">
    <div class="likelyOddHeader" id="Test3">
        <div class="likelyOddA">Test3</div>
        <div class="likelyOddB"><img src="image002.png"/></div>
        <div class="timeZone">West</div>
    </div>
```

//More closing tags here

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Test1').click(function() {
$('#Test1').appendTo('#unlikelyToBeCalled')
)};
)};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#Test1').click(function() {
        $('#Test1').appendTo('#unlikelyToBeCalled')
     });
});
```

(two last lines)

I tested it and it worked as **I** thought it would.

Using any browser developer tool (like the [Chrome console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)), you would have seen the javascript error.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm still (very) new to Jquery so the syntax (switching from java / C++) is a little weird.

Comment: You'll get used to it. Don't forget all your C++ habits, as you'll need to optimize a lot of things for complex web applications. The thing to get is that js is functionnal and event based.